# Can not use CRUDController

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, sonata-admin

I'm using sonata Mongodb AdminBundle for my back-end, in my case I need to create a new action for my user model ( sending a mail to him ), I followed the documentation literally 
https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/cookbook/recipe_custom_action.html 
but I got a weird error :

> Compile Error: Cannot use Sonata\AdminBundle\Controller\CRUDController as Controller because the name is already in use

and this is my CRUDController Code :

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Session\UserBundle\Document\User;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Controller\CRUDController as Controller;

class CrudController extends Controller
{
    public function inscriptionAction()
    {
        $mail = 'towho@someone.com';
        $pinCode = '1klm8';
        $sender = 'Mymail@gmail.com';

        $dm = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')->getManager();
        $userManager = $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager');

        $user = $userManager->createUser();
        $user->setEmail($mail);
        $user->setUsername($mail);
        $user->setPlainPassword($pinCode);
        $user->setEnabled(true);
        $userManager->updateUser($user, true);


        $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
            ->setSubject('Test de recrutement')
            ->setFrom($sender)
            ->setTo($mail)
            ->setCharset('utf-8')
            ->setContentType('text/html')
            ->setBody(
                $this->renderView(
                    'ATSQuizzBundle:Default:SwiftLayout/createUser.html.twig',
                    array('user' => $user, 'pinCode' => $pinCode)
                )
            );

        $this->get('mailer')->send($message);
        $this->addFlash('sonata_flash_success', 'mail sent to the candidate');

        return new RedirectResponse($this->admin->generateUrl('list'));
    }
}
```

any one knows the origin of this error please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have already imported the `Controller` class. And so you need to rename it in the second case. Override your use-block with next:

```
use Session\UserBundle\Document\User;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Controller\CRUDController as Controller;
```

As you see I deleted first occurrence of `Controller` class that is not used in your code. But if you have some other code in this file that can use "old" `Controller` I would recommend you to rename last `Controller` to `BaseController` and extend your class from `BaseController`.